# Scrolling Through Layouts

Tags: android, google-glass

I have an activity with five different layouts.  I want to scroll through each layout.  I looked at the CardScrollView example thinking I could put each layout on a different card, but it isn't clear to me how I setup a card with a layout. I see how I can add text or images, but not set the entire content of a card to my layout.  Or maybe there is a different way to accomplish my overall objective.

Answer (score 0):

The `getView` method of `CardScrollAdapter` can return any kind of view, not just those from `Card` instances. Instead of creating `Card` objects, use a `LayoutInflater` to inflate your own layouts, populate the widgets with values, and then return the root view from `getView`.